# Order and principal part of $f(x)=\, e^{x^2} \int_{x}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt$, infinitesimal as $x\to+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, infinitesimals

Determine if $f(x)$ is an infinite or an infinitesimal as $x\to+\infty$, its order and the principal part
$$f(x)=\, e^{x^2} \int_{x}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt$$

I can write, and then, using L'Hôpital's rule:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{x}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt}{e^{-x^2}}\,=\,\lim_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x^2}}{2xe^{-x^2}}\, = \, \lim_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{1}{2x}\,=\,0$$

So, $f(x)$ is an infinitesimal as $x\to+\infty$.

I am not sure of what I have done in order to determine the order and the principal part:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{x}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt}{e^{-x^2}}\setminus\dfrac{1}{x^{\alpha}}\,=\,\lim_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{x}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt}{x^{-\alpha}e^{-x^2}}\, = (H)\,= \, \lim_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x^2}}{e^{-x^2}x^{-\alpha-1}(\alpha+2x^2)}\,=\,\lim_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+2x^2}\,=\, L \iff \alpha=1$$

hence, the order of the infinitesimal is $1$ and the principal part of the infinitesimal is $\dfrac{1}{x}$

Is my solution correct or am I wrong? Thank you

Comment: Just a question: if you have shown $f$ vanishes as $\frac1{2x}$, isn’t it of order $1$?

Comment: It should be $x^{\alpha+1}$ in the numerator.

Comment: @Empy2 you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Szeto commented, you showed that $f(x)$ behaves as $\frac 1{2x}$; so order $1$ seems to be the answer.

Assuming that you already know the error function
$$\int_{x}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2}\, \text{erfc}(x)$$ then
$$f(x)=\, e^{x^2} \int_{x}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2}\, \text{erfc}(x)\, e^{x^2}$$ and, if you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Asymptotic_expansion)
$$\operatorname{erfc}(x) = \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2n - 1)!!}{(2x^2)^n}$$  making
$$f(x)=\frac 1 {2x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2n - 1)!!}{(2x^2)^n}=\frac{1}{2 x}-\frac{1}{4 x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you Szeto, I had never seen the error function yet :) and I made a mistake with signs in the last part

Comment: @F.inc. You are welcome ! Be sure that you will learn it soon and will have to use it many, many, many, many times ! Cheers